# iOS / WatchKit: Is there a way for the watch kit app(swift) to use the iOS code (Objective C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, watchkit

I thought about using a bridging header, but I keep getting fail to import bridging header. Is it possible for watch extension (written in swift) to use code from the iOS App (written in Objective C)? I need to make sure I am doing this correctly and professionally. If I can use bridging header, why am I getting the following error?

> :0: error: failed to import bridging header

Comment: is the bridging header path correct in your build settings?

Comment: I put the bridging header in my watch kit extension build settings

Comment: are you using cocoapods?

Comment: No, I am not using cocoapods

Comment: @DangerVeger did you find the solution for this ? I am having the issue with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might something as simple as a path problem. But what I normally do is create a dummy Objective-C file so that Xcode will create that bridging header for me, then I just copy and paste the path into the extension's build settings.

I've included a demo project which calls a method from an Objective-C file that is imported in the bridging header. I've also had to add the file in the extension's build phases for it to work. I hope this is what you're looking to solve.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5296996/WKTest.zip

Comment: Hi Sean,  how can you target the TestObj to be used in Watch Extension?  I created my own, and set the target of the .m file to WatchKit Extension, but WatchExtension still do not recognize the Objective-C object I create.